# Window switch works when it wants to

Tags: electrical, jeep, power-windows, liberty

I bought an aftermarket window master switch for a Jeep Liberty it works most of the time when it stops working and all I do is unplug it and plug it back in and it works fine for about a week then stops working I unplug it works again for another week Ideas to fix the problem thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely a galvanic reaction between the metal of the contact in the connector and the metal in the switch, especially if the switch is an aftermarket one (read: Chinesium). When you disconnect the two and put them back together, the interference is broken and the connection is restored ... until there is a new buildup between the two.

If this is the issue, you can most likely cure the issue by using a small jewelers file or possible a small strip of sandpaper where the contacts meet. Sand it to bare metal, the put some dielectric grease (sparingly) where the contacts meet. The dielectric grease should help with the galvanic reaction and allow the electricity to flow unabated.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly a loose connection in the circuit or switch.

Comment: Thanks but I just want to say it never happened with the old switch I replaced the switch because the button broke, Have had two after markets switches they both do the same if I put the original switch and it’s fine

Comment: The fact that you undo it and it then woks would suggest the connection is not perfect-i would clean all connections. Use mutimeter and check each part of the switch circuit.